# Is there a windows app that allows you to save and reopen multiple CMD(command line prompt)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line

Is there a windows app that allows you to save and reopen multiple CMD(command line prompt)including where it was saved?

For example,

```
CMD1 -> c:\
CMD2 -> c:\folder2
CMD3 -> c:\folder1\folder1folder1folder1folder1\folder1folder2\
CMD4 -> D:\folder1\folder1folder1folder1folder1\folder1folder2\newFolder\
```

I know writing a bat would probably do the trick but it's hard coded place...
Is there a app that I can save CMD 1 - 4 and reopen all of them at their saved path ?

Thanks

Comment: Console2 lets you create tab templates that open to specific paths: http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

Comment: Does it have save and reload ?

Comment: Yes, you can save the template for a specific path and load that tab at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) and [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) can do what you want.

In ConEmu, set up a *Task Group*, and then add tabs to that task group. You can customize the 
startup directory for each tab. Then go to the `Starup` config and set that task group as the named task group to load on startup.